# How to disable web service call tracking in Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, security

I am developing a project in Angular 4.0 and using c#.net web API as back-end.

Problem is, When I am running my application through browser, I am able to see web service call (get/post) through "Postman Interceptor". Which is not good for security. Is there any way to secure my webAPI call so that it will not be visible in "Postmatser" or fiddler like tool?

Comment: There is nothing bad for security. By running Fiddler, you actually set up a MITM on your local machine. You don't want and don't need to make user unable to "hack" his own machine's calls. Nobody, except for you, can see these requests if you use HTTPS.

Comment: No. You can't.... Always assume any api is exposed and secure it server side

Comment: `AngularJS` = Angular 1. `Angular` = Angular 2+. `AngularJS 4` = spacetime ripping

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev _"Nobody, except for you, can see these requests if you use HTTPS"_ - Fiddler can install a certificate and decrypt all requests and responses. HTTPS hides nothing from the user, but only from MITM not running on your machine.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, I mean, that's ok, because whoever makes a requests did run this MITM proxy on his own. Nobody between server and a client can see these requests.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to secure my webAPI call so that it will not be visible in [Postman or Fiddler]?

No. You're issuing requests from the browser. This means they will come from the visitor's pc, and everything that happens there can be intercepted by them.

You don't need obscurity, you need authentication.